# How do you generate random patterns and convert them to an image?

Tags: java, image

I am currently making a game. I have multiple users and for each user I have a id (UUID). I was hoping to use this id as like a key to generate a random pattern then to a image for that player.

```
boolean[] booleanPlayerID = BSUtility.bytesToBooleans(playerID.getBytes(UTF_8));
WritableImage image = new WritableImage(50, 50);
PixelWriter writer = image.getPixelWriter();
int booleanIndex = 0;
for(int y = 0; 50 > y; y++){
    for(int x = 0; 50 > x; x++){
        if(booleanIndex >= booleanPlayerID.length){
            booleanIndex = 0;
        }

        if(booleanPlayerID[booleanIndex]){
            writer.setColor(x, y, Color.BLACK);
        }
        booleanIndex++;
    }
}
```

Assuming the image is going to be 50x50... What I have been doing is I take the player's id, convert to boolean array, cycle through image pixels, also cycle through boolean array, if the boolean value is true then set the pixel color to black. The if statement is to avoid indexing out of bounds (I know I should probably convert the boolean array to be the same length as how many pixels are in the image)...

This does produce some what of a pattern, but to be honest it is a really shitty pattern. The patterns generally tend to be very similar to one another. I was wondering if someone could provide tips/example of how to do this better. With my little research I really couldn't find much. I did however find patterns that I am hoping to somewhat obtain, I believe they are called tangle patterns. I would really hope to have each user have their own unique image/pattern but obvious it is fine if they are somewhat similar but not same. I don't know if this is possible to be honest.

If you need a complete example I can replace the code above. Although the code above should be pretty straight forward to making it a full example (only things missing is generating the userID and converting it to boolean array from bytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is known as **`IDENTICON`**.

I actually don't know how they work but i know that they use some sort of hashing with the **`UNIQUE TEXT`** and generate image with that hash.

Here are two website i found who do provide source code so if you are interested you can look into the code and extract any useful information from there.

1. http://identicon.net/
2. https://jdenticon.com/

**PS. Code are in JavaScript and on one website its in .NET and PHP too.**

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.